# Matching regular expressions

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have a regular expression, it's basically to update log4j syntax to log4j2 syntax, removing the string replacement. The regular expression is as follows

```
(?:^\(\s*|\s*\+\s*|,\s*)(?:[\w\(\)\.\d+]*|\([\w\(\)\.\d+]*\s*(?:\+|-)\s*[\w\(\)\.\d+]*\))(?:\s\+\s*|\s*\);)
```

This will successfully match the variables in the following strings

```
("Unable to retrieve things associated with this='" + thingId + "' in " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms");
("Persisting " + things.size() + " new or updated thing(s)");
("Count in use for thing=" + secondThingId + " is " + countInUse);
("Unable to check thing state '" + otherThingId + "' using '" + address + "'", e);
```

But not '+ thingCollection.get(0).getMyId()' in

```
("Exception occured while updating thingId="+ thingCollection.get(0).getMyId(), e);
```

I am getting better with regular expressions, but this one has me a bit stumped. Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry for not being up to reading that regex carefully -- how do you want to change those lines?  Can you state it, or show the desired output?

Comment: So basically what I want to do is parse any strings out, in order, and then parse out any of the variables or function calls in order to make 

`("Unable to check thing state '" + otherThingId + "' using '" + address + "'", e);`    look like    
`("Unable to check thing state '{}' using '{}'", otherThingId, address, e);`

Comment: You need to show the code that uses this regex pattern *in context* so that we can see what you need it to do. Otherwise I can only suggest that `/.*/` will match all of your statements.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, when some people are writing a regex pattern, they forget that the whole of the Perl language is still available

I would just delete all the strings and find the remaining substrings that look like variable names

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature qw/ say fc /;

use List::Util 'uniq';

my @variables;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    s/"[^"]*"//g;
    push @variables, /\b[a-z]\w*/ig;
}

say for sort { fc $a cmp fc $b } uniq @variables;

__DATA__
("Unable to retrieve things associated with this='" + thingId + "' in " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms");
("Persisting " + things.size() + " new or updated thing(s)");
("Count in use for thing=" + secondThingId + " is " + countInUse);
("Unable to check thing state '" + otherThingId + "' using '" + address + "'", e);
("Exception occured while updating thingId="+ thingCollection.get(0).getMyId(), e);
```

#### output

```
address
countInUse
e
endTime
get
getMyId
otherThingId
secondThingId
size
startTime
thingCollection
thingId
things
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simplify your regex to match things in between '+' signs.

`(?:\+)([^"]*?)(?:[\+,])`
[Working Example](https://regex101.com/r/n2aCnh/2)

(Note the ? after the * this makes the * lazy so it matches as little as possible to catch all occurrences)

If you want just the variable you could access the first capture group from that expression or ignore the capture group to get the full match.

---

Updated Version `(?:\+)([^"]*?)(?:[\+,])|\s([^"+]*?)\);`[Working Example](https://regex101.com/r/n2aCnh/3)

Note with the new version that the variable might get placed into capture group 2 instead of 1

Comment: I like the example, though this does miss matching the `, e)` and `countInUse` as a variable at the end of 

`("Count in use for thing=" + secondThingId + " is " + countInUse);`

`("Unable to check thing state '" + otherThingId + "' using '" + address + "'", e);`

 `("Exception occured while updating thingId="+ thingCollection.get(0).getMyId(), e);`

Comment: I updated the expression to include a case for those end variables

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to pare it down to this `(?:^\(\s*|\s*\+\s*|,\s*)(?:[\w().\s+]+|\([\w().\s+-]*\))(?:(?=,)|\s*\+\s*|\s*\);)`

[101 regex](https://regex101.com/r/n2aCnh/5)

It consolidates some constructs.

To fix the immediate problem, I added a comma in some classes.
A note that this kind of regex is fraught with problematic type of flow.

```
 (?:
      ^ \( \s* 
   |  \s* \+ \s* 
   |  , \s* 
 )
 (?:
      [\w().\s+]+ 
   |  \( [\w().\s+-]* \) 
 )
 (?:
      (?= , )
   |  \s* \+ \s* 
   |  \s* \); 
 )
```

Comment: This is close, though I notice with this one it doesn't seem split the  `thingCollection.get(0).getMyId(), e);` in `("Exception occured while updating thingId="+ thingCollection.get(0).getMyId(), e);`

Comment: `**  Grp 0 -  ( pos 366 , len 39 ) 
+ thingCollection.get(0).getMyId(), e); ` looks like _split_ to me  https://regex101.com/r/n2aCnh/4

Comment: The regex101 link you sent shows it as matching ` + thingCollection.get(0).getMyId(), e);` not ` + thingCollection.get(0).getMyId(),` and ` e);` Note, the comma can be on either side, doesn't really matter to me

Comment: Update post. [(?:^\(\s*|\s*\+\s*|,\s*)(?:\[\w().\s+\]+|\(\[\w().\s+-\]*\))(?:(?=,)|\s*\+\s*|\s*\);)](https://regex101.com/r/n2aCnh/5)